# Sky texture not working properly

Tags: lighting, shadows, properties, world

Sky texture is not showing any shadows and changing intensity in properties has no effect. Some other features are off too.

[image]

I tried changing elevation rotation everything still no effect.

Comment: Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ? Could you detail what you mean by "Some other features are off too" ?

Comment: The _Material Preview_ is primarily for showing the materials, as the name suggests, not the lighting conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You are in *Material* preview mode, this mode works like Eevee, in this mode you won't have any shadow from the HDRI, if you are in Eevee and if you switch to *Rendered* preview you can fake the shadows though: Create a *Light Probe> Irradiance Volume*, in the *Render panel > Indirect Lightint* click on *Bake Indirect Lighting*.